# Instance member 'layer' cannot be used on type 'CustomPrettyView'

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit 
class CustomPrettyView: UIView { 
    override class func awakeFromNib() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 20 
    } 
}
```

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 5):

`class func` declare type level methods. They are similar to static func but `class func` methods can be overridden by subclasses.

There are two implementations of `func awakeFromNib` that you can override:

- one of them is instance level method
- and the other is type level method.

Only instance level method has access to non-static members of a class like `layer`, `mask`, `supreview` and so on. Read here more about type level methods: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html

Thus, by removing `class` keyword you'll fix the issue:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // rest of code
     }
```

Comment: Why? Why?! WHY!? ‍♂️

Comment: @olivaresF, `class func` declare type level methods. They are similar to `static func` but `class func` methods can be overridden by subclasses. 
There are two implementations of `func awakeFromNib` that you can override: one of them is instance level method and the other is type level method. Only instance level method has access to non-static members of a class like `layer`, `mask`, `supreview` and so on. Read here more about type level methods: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html

Comment: @olivaresF, looked at your profile. I guess the intention of the question "Why?" was different :) I'll modify the answer. Anyway, useful information.

Comment: Haha, yes, I'm sorry. I was just very frustrated that I messed this one up. I upvoted your answer! Thanks for your help 